# How to find the background color in html specifically on the reddit website

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to find the background color that controls the Reddit website. I've gone into the inspect element and found a few "backgrounds" but they didn't affect the background color when I changed it. There should be a simple way of finding the background color that controls the website. (I've been trying to find the background color for dark mode; I'm not sure if this is important but the subreddit is AskReddit).

I've tried to use inspect element, DreamWeaver, SeaMonkey, and page source.

Comment: ._1vyLCp-v-tE5QvZovwrASa {
    background: black;
}
works for me.

Comment: I'm very new to HTML/CSS so could you make a short video or screenshot the process, it would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: I simply inspect element and scroll down the code until the part I want to change highlights on the Graphical section ( the web page ), from there it is very easy to find the corresponding css.

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect element, then scroll up and down the HTML until the part you're interested highlights on the webpage. Here, you see it overlayed with green. It tells me in two locations what the class is, so I go to the css of that class and change it.

[image]

Comment: No problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

it may set background color in multiple section but in Body or Html section you can find or even change it
background-color:......